# Why a line has dimension 1?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I'm studying linear algebra. I've understood that a line that passes throught the origin is a 1-dimensional object since i can describe it with only a vector and a real variable.

But, why also a line that doesn't pass throught the origin is a 1 dimensional object ?

Comment: A line not through the origin is the set of points of the form $\vec v t + \vec b$, so it is also described by $1$ real variable, $t$.

Comment: Morally, the dimension of a thing shouldn't change just because you choose to put the origin somewhere else. If it has dimension $1$ when you place the origin on the line, then it ought to have dimension $1$ when you place the origin someplace else.

Comment: $y = mx +b$ the $x$ is a single variable.  The $b$ is a constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that by definition the dimension of an **affine space** is equal to the dimension of the **vector space** of its translations, therefore also a line that doesn't pass throught the origin is defined as $1$ dimensional object.

Comment: This is trivial but maybe a statement that a line that doesn't pass through the origin is a simple *translation* of one that does, would make this all the clearer?

Comment: @fleablood Yes of course but in that way the fact can be generalized also to n-dimensional case.

Comment: Why is it important to know that a line has dimension 1 ?

Comment: @Qwerto the dimension is an important concept to establish the number of basis vectors (or free parameters) we need to describe a subspace.